# Google Cloud Firebase: [[GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006]] There was an error saving the new counter value to disk

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

- Xcode version: 11.4.1
- Firebase SDK version: (6.24.0)
- Firebase Component: Core, Firestore
- Component version: Core (6.7.0), Firestore (1.13.0) (GoogleDataTransport (6.1.0))
- Installation method: Cocoapods (1.9.1)

I'm new to IOS development and this is my first time using Firebase. I've been going through the process of setting the SDK up. I've followed all of the steps exactly, but I'm incapable of passing the "Run your app to verify installation" step. I feel that it might be connected to this error I get whenever I run my app:

```
[GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006]
/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCOREvent.m:59) : There was an error saving the new counter value to disk.
```

The error doesn't crash my app, and it doesn't fail the build either. It just appears in the console whenever I run my app. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Cocoapods several times, I've also tried making an entirely new project and attaching it to Firebase, but this error persists. If it helps, this is the specific GDTCOREvent.m:59 section it refers to:

```
__block NSNumber *result;
  dispatch_sync(eventIDQueue, ^{
    result = @(nextEventID);
    nextEventID++;
    NSError *error;
    [[result stringValue] writeToFile:counterPath
                           atomically:YES
                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                error:&error];
    GDTCORAssert(error == nil, @"There was an error saving the new counter value to disk.");
  });
```

How do I fix this error, and would it at all help the problem of communication between my app and the servers?

[The original post on the firebase-ios-sdk github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5549)

Comment: Including your podfile would be helpful. Also, did you create your project in Firebase and drag the *GoogleService-Info.plist* file to your project?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem previously and I was only able to fix it by uninstalling xcode and all of cocoapods and re-downloading it